# java 8 groupingBy, Filter records for fields greater than average

Tags: java, group-by, java-8, aggregate-functions

Trying to learn java 8 GroupingBy Country Im am trying to filter records (people) who are above the average age (Collecting) returning a list of people who satisfy this criteria.

So the SQL equivalent is

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON, AVG(AGE) AS AVG_AGE
GROUPBY COUNTRY
WHERE AGE > AVG_AGE
```

This is my attempt so far which only took me half way

```
personStream.collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    p -> p.getCountry(),
                    Collectors.averagingInt(p -> p.getAge)))
```

So far this only returns me a Map with the classifier as the key and the average age by country as the value.

```
Chan, Japan, 40
Chong, Japan, 20
Amy, Japan, 37
James, UK, 25
Abby, UK, 15,
Jean, France 15
Pierre, France, 50

Average Japanese age = 32.33
Average UK age = 20
Average French age = 32.5

ResultSet
Chan, Japan, 40
Chong, Japan, 20
Amy, Japan, 37
James, UK, 25
Pierre, France, 50
```

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: I think you must iterate over the list twice - once to calculate the average age for each country (as you already do), and a second time in which you apply a filter that uses the map produced in the first step to determine is a person's age is higher than the average age.

Comment: In SQL you should use HAVING clause to filter the group by result.

Comment: As @Tagir Valeev mentioned, when you refer to the aggregated value in your condition, you most likely want `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`, however, wtf is `WHERE NAME > AVG_AGE` supposed to do? Compare a name with an age⁈

Comment: sorry that was a mistake. i think you knew what i meant. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will not be able to do that in one pass. 2 passes are necessary: the first to calculate the average and the second to filter the persons having an age greater than the average.

Note that the SQL query you wrote won't work [for the same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992430/1743880): you can't reference a column alias inside a WHERE clause.

Your code calculates properly the average age for persons living in the same country. Therefore, we need add the code that filters the initial `persons` list.

```
Map<String, Double> map =
        persons.stream().collect(
            groupingBy(
                p -> p.getCountry(),
                averagingInt(p -> p.getAge())
            )
        );

persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > map.get(p.getCountry())).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to .filter(p -> p.getAge() > averageAge) somehow collecting that averageAge from that map you are getting now.