# Find out employees average Salary greater than 8000 within their Department

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to find the employees average salary greater than `8000` within their `department`

I got the `avg(salary)` within the department greater than `8000` but could not display the names

```
select avg(salary) from employees group by department_id having avg(salary)> 8000
```

it show the employees name

Comment: Please make this a complete question by including sample data.

Comment: What is an employee's average salary? Doesn't every employee only have single salary? Do you mean salary should be greater than 8000 and greater than department average? For that, you could build on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992412/oracle-show-all-employees-with-greater-than-average-salary-of-their-department?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select department_id, emp_name, salary from
(select department_id, emp_name, salary, avg(salary) over(partition by department_id) as avg_salary 
from employees)
Where avg_salary >= 8000 
AND salary >= 8000; -- ADDED THIS CONDITION
```

Above query will return all the employees within the department having average salaries of employees greater than 8000 with department id, employee name and their salary.

Cheers!!

Comment: thnx dear. but its also showing the salary of the employees less than 8000. in output we should only see above 8000. This is like first calculate avg salary of each department and filter above 8000 then list the name of employees with the salary